# Drawing an image from URL

Tags: java, image, url

It's for a pacman game and it works perfectly when I import it from my computer. But when I try to take it from an URL, my game starts lagging and the image doesn't show.

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.dropbox.com/s/xpc49t8xpqt8dir/pacman%20down.jpg");
image = ImageIO.read(url);  

G.drawImage(image, x, y, 20,20,null);
```

### Image

[image: PacMan]

( https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp1XL.png at IMGUR )

Comment: This icon should be an [tag:embedded-resource] that is supplied in one of the Jar files. Please edit existing questions rather than duplicate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it may lag because the program downloads the image each time you draw it with your `Graphics` object. You should use a cache system for your image or download it once for all the program execution.

Answer (score 5):

`https://www.dropbox.com/s/xpc49t8xpqt8dir/pacman%20down.jpg` is return HTML text not image data.

This is a hack, but try `https://www.dropbox.com/s/xpc49t8xpqt8dir/pacman%20down.jpg?dl=1` instead.  Be warned though, it's possible that drop box could change this query in the future.

[image]

```
public class TestURL02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestURL02();
    }

    public TestURL02() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new PacPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PacPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage image;

        public PacPane() {
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://www.dropbox.com/s/xpc49t8xpqt8dir/pacman%20down.jpg?dl=1");
//                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
//                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
//                is = url.openStream();
//                int in = -1;
//                while ((in = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
//                    sb.append(new String(buffer));
//                }
//                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                image = ImageIO.read(url);
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return image == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (image != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - image.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - image.getHeight()) / 2;
                g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the requisite security.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's possible, I've browsed over to the page and can see the image, I've also "hacked" a download solution

Comment: @AndrewThompson Fat fingers and stupid computer that needs to pause every 30 seconds to "think"

Comment: BTW - I just tried the image by the link given by both you & the OP in the browser & it showed 404.  Maybe DB ..dropped it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The OP just re-posted the question again :P

Comment: Your code works fine using the image I embedded here (see update to question).  I expect it would work in the OP's code.  I voted to close the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

My guess, and it's only a guess because you don't tell us, but could you possibly be trying to read in the Image from the URL from within a Swing or AWT `paint(...)` or `paintComponent(...)` method? If so, don't do this. Read the image in once, and then *use* it in the `paintComponent(...)` method.

If this doesn't help, please do tell us the details we'll need to know to be able to help  you.

Comment: Yep, Im using awt. I changed it like this, no lag but still no image:                                                               public Image getImage() throws IOException{
     URL url = new URL("https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2mpnu0kzc6s7ot/pacman%20down.png");
  return image = ImageIO.read(url);   
    }                                                         protected void paintComponent(Graphics G) throws IOException{
         G.drawImage(image, x, y, 20,20,null);     
    }